# Sencha Touch 2: How do I divide my DataView into two sections with different headers?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a tab panel in my app and on the "My Reviews" tab, there should be a section for reviews submitted by the user, and another for reviews that were only "liked" by the user. Currently, I am populating a single dataview with JSON that includes all reviews the user interacted with, and there is no separation between user submitted reviews and user "liked" reviews. I would like to split these two up and give a heading for each.

My tab looks like this:

```
{
            title: 'Reviews Dashboard',
            iconCls: 'action',
            layout: 'fit',
            xtype: 'reviewsdashboard'


            items: [
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'Reviews Dashboard'

                }

            ] 

        }
```

and my "Reviews Dashboard" DataView looks like this:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
'<div class=dashbox>',
'<div class="col1">${starRating} for {movietitle}</div>',
'<div class="col2">Submitted by {user}</div>',
'<div class="col3">{status}</div>',
'</div>'
);

Ext.define('MyApp.view.ReviewsDashboard',
{
extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
xtype: 'reviewsdashboard',
config:
{
    xtype: 'dataview',
    title: 'Reviews Dashboard',
    itemTpl: tpl,

    store:
    {
        autoLoad: true,

        fields: [
            {
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'user',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'movietitle',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'starRating',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'date',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'status',
                type: 'string'
            }

        ],

        proxy:
        {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: MyApp.util.Config.getBaseUrl() +
                '/getReviews.php',
            reader:
            {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'listing'
            }
      }
   }
 }
});
```

How can I split my dataview into two sections and assign a title or header for each section? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you mean the 2 different views on one tab, or in a separate tab? Please clarify. If in 1 tab you would have to use a container to hold the 2 dataviews, the layout would be hbox on the container (horizontal box i.e. stacked side by side). Each dataview would have a flex config of 0.5.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was hoping to have a single dataview in a single tab displayed in two separate boxes. Are you suggesting I use two dataviews, or is there a way to use the same dataview but populate one container with certain values and populate the other container with the remaining values?

Comment: You could have 2 different data views, but they would both be using the same model and store. In each data view template (tpl) you could filter the store results for each using {item name} in the template. Do a search for 'conditional tpl data view' and you should find something.